How to extract statistical data about citations in a section?
I'm writing a paper in which I need to plot some statistics about the references cited in one of its sections, e.g., the total number of citations grouped by the reference type. I'm using biblatex and biber to handle the references. The following table is an example of the data that should be plotted:



Type
Citations




Articles
13


Books
9


Websites
4



To achieve this, I believe that at some point a spreadsheet should be generated so that I could use it as the data source for the plots, but, given my needs, I don't know if this would be possible.
Seeking to understand what data is generated when compiling the document, I discovered that biber would be able to handle some of them and generate files that could be converted to a CSV at the end of the day. However, extracting the data I need would still be a problem.
How could I solve this?

There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454182/35864 for example. Generally speaking, biblatex does not know about your document sectioning unless you explicitly pair up your document sections also with biblatex "sectioning tools" like refsections or refsegments.

Related and possibly interesting as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66829/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536694/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495992/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404259/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609226/35864.

@moewe awesome, I hadn't found any of these before. I'll take a look at them. Thank you!
